# Event driven classes in C#

Tags: c#, events

I am creating an event driven class so that when I pass it a series of data, it will process and then return the value when ready.

Below is the code that I am currently using the below code however it is quite nasty and I'm not sure if can be simpler than this.

```
   public delegate void MyEventHandler(double result);

    public static MyEventHandler EventComplete;

    public static void MakeSomethingHappen(double[] data)
    {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(DoSomething, data);
    }
    private static void DoSomething(object dblData)
    {
        InvokeEventComplete(AndSomethingElse((double[])dblData));
    }

    private static void InvokeEventComplete(double result)
    {
        if (EventComplete != null)
        {
            EventComplete(result);
        }
    }

    public static double AndSomethingElse(double[] data)
    {
         //do some code
         return result; //double
    }
```

In my main class I simply hook up a method to the event like so,

```
MyClass.EventComplete += new MyClass.EventCompleteHandler(MyClass_EventComplete);
```

Comment: Might be a better fit for http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Do you really need everything to be static ? Also, consider following the standard event pattern where the delegate is `EventHandler<T>`.

Comment: @BoltClock I really need to pay more attention to the SE's coming through Area51. good find :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you are:

- Exposed event as an actual event rather than a publicly accessible member delegate.
- Eliminated extra delegate declaration and used generic delegate Action.
- Eliminated extra invocation function which was simply verbose.
- Used lambda expression for event registration.

Edited code is:

```
MyClass.EventComplete += (result) => Console.WriteLine("Result is: " + result);

public class MyClass
{
    public static event Action<double> EventComplete;

    public static void MakeSomethingHappen(double[] data)
    {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(DoSomething, data);
    }

    private static void DoSomething(object dblData)
    {
        var result = AndSomethingElse((double[])dblData);

        if (EventComplete != null)
        {
            EventComplete(result);
        }
    }

    public static double AndSomethingElse(double[] data)
    {
        //do some code
        return result; //double
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Some things to consider...

There's an `EventHandler<T> where T : EventArgs` in .NET, but the trade off is you end up writing a custom EventArgs to pass your double data instead of a custom delegate. Still I think that's a cleaner pattern to follow.

If you were to define your event as

```
public static MyEventHandler EventComplete = delegate {};
//using a no-op handler like this has implications on Garbage Collection
```

[Does using a no-op lambda expression for initializing an event prevent GC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945423/does-using-a-no-op-lambda-expression-for-initializing-an-event-prevent-gc)

you could save yourself the if(EventComplete != null) check everytime and hence make the Invoke... method redundant.

you can also simplify

```
MyClass.EventComplete += new MyClass.EventCompleteHandler(MyClass_EventComplete);
to
MyClass.EventComplete += MyClass_EventComplete;
```

Aside from that it looks fine. I presume all the `static`'s around the code are just from working in a ConsoleApplication :-)

Answer (score 0):

try using standart event pattern (thousands times used inside FCL)

```
// in [CompleteEventArgs.cs] file
public class CompleteEventArgs : EventArgs {
    private readonly double _result;

    public CompleteEventArgs(double result) {
        _result = result;
    }

    public double Result {
        get { return _result; }
    }
}

// inside your class

// don't forget 'event' modifier(!) it prevents lots of illegal stuff
// like 'Complete = null' on the listener side
public static event EventHandler<CompleteEventArgs> Complete;

public static void MakeSomethingHappen(double[] data) {
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(DoSomething, data);
}
private static void DoSomething(object dblData) {
    OnComplete(new CompleteEventArgs(AndSomethingElse((double[])dblData)));
}

// if you're working with a 'normal' (non-static) class
// here should be 'protected virtual' modifiers to allow inheritors
// use polymorphism to change the business logic
private static void OnComplete(CompleteEventArgs e) {
    if (Complete != null)
        Complete(null, e); // in 'normal' way here stands 'this' instead of 'null'
                           // this object (link to the sender) is pretty tricky
                           // and allows extra flexibility of the code on the listener side
}

public static double AndSomethingElse(double[] data) {
    double result = 0;
    //do some code
    return result; //double
}
```

Comment: @Kyle: please note the similar error (bug/mistake) in @Teoman's answer! event must(!) be field with 'event' modifier. in his code it is possible to write MyClass.EventComplete = null; from any part of the code and it will cause terrible things happen;) even using {get;private set;} is bad. sorry, I don't have enough rep to comment his post